# add product value to add to cart button

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I want to show product value ( version ) to my add to cart button in the single product page

i found the file that must be edit :  woocommerce\templates\single-product\add-to-cart\external.php

```
<button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt"><?php echo esc_html( $button_text ); ?> </button>
```

i try to change it to :

```
<button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt"><?php echo wp_kses_post( $product_attribute['value'] ); ?> </button>
```

but now nothing shows on my add to cart button

Answer (score 0):

Just try adding this in `functions.php` file of your active theme

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 10, 2 );

function woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text( $add_to_cart, $product ) {
    return $add_to_cart."--".$product->get_price();
}
```